# TensorFlow Custom Estimator - Restore model after small changes in model_fn

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am using `tf.estimator.Estimator` for developing my model,

I wrote a `model_fn` and trained 50,000 iterations, now I want to make a small change in my `model_fn`, for example add a new layer.

I don't want to start training from scratch, I want to restore all the old variables from the 50,000 checkpoint, and continue training from this point. When I try to do so I get a `NotFoundError`

How can this be done with `tf.estimator.Estimator`?

Comment: Can you provide the full error trace please? It could help to get more context for the error.

Comment: Here is a toy example: https://gist.github.com/mtngld/147335874af6fe5d79a5673406679640

Comment: My original question was about `model_fn` but in that gist I am actually seeing the same error when using generic DNNClassifier when adding new layers. Thanks!

Comment: Related tf issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10155

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR** The easiest way to load variables from a previous checkpoint is to use the function [`tf.train.init_from_checkpoint()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/init_from_checkpoint). Just one call to this function inside the `model_fn` of your Estimator will override the initializers of the corresponding variables.

---

### First model with two hidden layers

In more details, suppose you have trained a first model with two hidden layers on MNIST, named `model_fn_1`. The weights are saved in directory `mnist_1`.

```py
def model_fn_1(features, labels, mode):
    images = features['image']

    h1 = tf.layers.dense(images, 100, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h1")
    h2 = tf.layers.dense(h1, 100, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h2")

    logits = tf.layers.dense(h2, 10, name="logits")

    loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

# Estimator 1: two hidden layers
estimator_1 = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn_1, model_dir='mnist_1')

estimator_1.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1000)
```

---

### Second model with three hidden layers

Now we want to train a new model `model_fn_2` with three hidden layers. We want to load the weights for the first two hidden layers `h1`and `h2`. We use `tf.train.init_from_checkpoint()` to do this:

```py
def model_fn_2(features, labels, mode, params):
    images = features['image']

    h1 = tf.layers.dense(images, 100, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h1")
    h2 = tf.layers.dense(h1, 100, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h2")
    h3 = tf.layers.dense(h2, 100, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h3")

    assignment_map = {
        'h1/': 'h1/',
        'h2/': 'h2/'
    }
    tf.train.init_from_checkpoint('mnist_1', assignment_map)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(h3, 10, name="logits")

    loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

# Estimator 2: three hidden layers
estimator_2 = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn_2, model_dir='mnist_2')

estimator_2.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1000)
```

The `assignment_map` will load every variable from scope `h1/` in the checkpoint into the new scope `h1/`, and same with `h2/`. Don't forget the `/` at the end to make TensorFlow know it's a variable scope.

---

I couldn't find a way to make this work using pre-made estimators, since you can't change their `model_fn`.