# TensorFlow Estimator unable to train second set of fully connected layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have an Estimator which trains a CNN with one particular loss function.  Once that training is completed, I would like to have the same Estimator, train a new set of fully connected layers using the already trained convolutional layers, and a new loss function.  These must be done one after another.

When attempting to start training the second set of fully connected layers I encounter the following error:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key OptimizeLoss/inception_module_1_path_1/batch_normalization/beta/Adam not found in checkpoint
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2_22 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_22/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_22/shape_and_slices)]]
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2_21/_1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_280_save/RestoreV2_21", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

It seems that it needs to have already set up the second loss function, but I thought that was done when the model_fn was run.  The Estimator is being trained with two consecutive Estimator.train method calls.

Comment: http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/

Comment: I'm aware this can be done by leaving the Estimator class, but ideally this would be done within the same Estimator, since everything is contained within the model_fn.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48127348/5098368), maybe that will help?